# Tweet button is getting rendered too late

Tags: vue.js, button, twitter, vuejs2

I'm using a tweet button on my website written on Vue.js and experiencing this issue that at first, the button shows up without appropriate styling, just a plain anchor tag text and after a while, it changes to its original stylish version. Here's the component I wrote:

```
<template>
    <span v-html="tweetButton">
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "MyComponent",
        mounted() {
            this.renderTweetButton()
        },
        watch: {
            twitter(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal.widgets) {
                    newVal.widgets.load()
                }
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                tweetButton: null,
                twitter: {}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            renderTweetButton() {
                this.tweetButton = `<a
                    class="twitter-share-button"
                    data-via="Example"
                    data-size="medium"
                    data-text="Check this out!"
                    data-url="https://example.com"
                    href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">
                  Tweet</a>`

                this.twitter = (function(d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                        t = window.twttr || {};
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.async = false;
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

                    t._e = [];
                    t.ready = function(f) {
                        t._e.push(f);
                    };

                    return t;
                }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"))
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

So I was just wondering if there's a way to don't show the button until it gets fully loaded ?

Comment: Since you appear to be downloading the button, wrap the call that downloads it in an async function.  After the dl finishes, set a boolean to display the button using v-if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the target anchor element is automatically replaced by the Twitter Widget upon the script loading, you could just hide the anchor with a `display:none` style to avoid the flash of unstyled content:

```js
this.tweetButton = `<a style="display: none" ...>`
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hide-anchor-while-twitter-widget-loads?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: @jjxtra I noticed a very long (>14s) connection delay to `unpkg.com`, which the demo relies on. The demo did eventually load. You probably experienced the same delay. That delay wasn't there when I first created the demo :)

Comment: @jjxtra I moved the demo to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hide-anchor-while-twitter-widget-loads?file=src%2FApp.vue) to avoid the issue.